# Multiple errors importing and using mglearn

Tags: python

I'm getting multiple errors trying to install and import the mglearn library into a Jupyter notebook.  I've installed mglearn using the command line using `pip install mglearn` and also directly into Jupyter using `!pip install mglearn`.  However, when I try to `import mglearn` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'`.  If I try to install it again I get a `Requirement already satisfied` response.

I then went into the python terminal with `$python3` and tried `import mglearn`, which was successful.  I checked the version and I get 0.1.7.

I've also tried the following code within Jupyter:

`import sys`

`!{sys.executable} -m pip install mglearn`

With that code I get a `zsh:1: no matches found:` error.

I know it's installed and I'm importing it.  I'm out of ideas for how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Jupyter is using the wrong Python version. Do `which python3` (run in zsh) and `print(sys.executable)` (run in Jupyter) output the same path?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but how do I run something in zsh?

Comment: Try `!which python3` in Jupyter or use your terminal

Comment: Ah, I see.  ```which python3``` shows ```.../anaconda/bin/python3``` and ```print(sys.executable)``` shows ```hands_on_ml/my_env/bin/python3```.  Different places.  Any fix for this?

Comment: your Jupyter somehow uses a virtual environment. You can learn more about Python virtual environments here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  I'm familiar with virtual environments and I've never had this problem with anything else.  I use Jupyter quite often with sklearn, pandas, etc.